# I am encountering an error while using imwrite

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to image processing and what I am trying to do is resize an image and store it in tif format, but command window reports an error saying "you don't have the permission to write"

my code is  `imwrite(B,'myNewFile.tif');`
and after running it shows

> Error using imwrite (line 10)
>   Unable to open file "myNewFile.tif" for writing.  You may not have write permission.

Do I have to create a file by the name `'myNewFile'` before writing the above code?

Comment: Did you try writing to a different working directory?

Comment: No, I did not try it earlier...but now I did and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you are trying to write the file `myNewFile.tif` to the current working directory. However, you do not have writing permission in the current working direcoty. This is an OS issue, not a Matlab one.

What you can do is change the current working directory (using `cd` command) and write the image to a different folder where you do have writing permissions.

Alternatively, you can supply a full path to the image file name, directing it to a folder where you have writing permissions.

```
imwrite( B, fullfile( '/path/to/where/you/can/write', 'myNewFile.tif' ) );
```

Here are links to the description of some Matlab commands that might help you:

- [`pwd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) can be used to check what is your current working directory.
- You can use [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) to change the current working directory.
- [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) helps you construct file names and paths in a generic way without worrying about OS pecularities.